# How to use CriticalSection - MFC?

Tags: multithreading, mfc, critical-section

I' am working on a small example and am  a bit of curious using criticalsection in my example.
What I'am doing is,I have a CStringArray(which has 10 elements added to it).I want to copy
these 10 elements(string) to another CStringArray(am doing this to understand threading and Critical section),I have created 2 threads,Thread1 will copy the first 5 element to another CStringArray and Thread2 will copy the rest.Here two CStringArray are being used,I know only 1 thread can access it at a time.I wanted to know how this can be solved by using criticalsection or any other method.

```
void CThreadingEx4Dlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    thread1 = AfxBeginThread((AFX_THREADPROC)MyThreadFunction1,this);
    thread2 = AfxBeginThread((AFX_THREADPROC)MyThreadFunction2,this);
}
UINT MyThreadFunction1(LPARAM lparam)
{
    CThreadingEx4Dlg* pthis = (CThreadingEx4Dlg*)lparam;

    pthis->MyFunction(0,5);
    return 0;
}
UINT MyThreadFunction2(LPARAM lparam)
{
    CThreadingEx4Dlg* pthis = (CThreadingEx4Dlg*)lparam;
    pthis->MyFunction(6,10);
    return 0;
}

void CThreadingEx4Dlg::MyFunction(int minCount,int maxCount)
{
    for(int i=minCount;i<=maxCount;i++)
    {
        CString temp;
        temp = myArray.GetAt(i);
        myShiftArray.Add(temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I'd use a CriticalSection is:

- Declare a member variable in your `CThreadingEx4Dlg` class:

  ```
  CCriticalSection m_CriticalSection;
  ```
- Enclose your not thread safe code in a Lock-Unlock block of this CriticalSection:

  ```
  void CThreadingEx4Dlg::MyFunction(int minCount,int maxCount)
  {
      m_CriticalSection.Lock();
      for(int i=minCount;i<=maxCount;i++)
          myShiftArray.Add(myArray.GetAt(i));
      m_CriticalSection.Unlock();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using CSingleLock so that the constructor takes care of the locking and the destructor automatically takes care of the unlocking

```
void CThreadingEx4Dlg::MyFunction(int minCount,int maxCount)
{
    CSingleLock myLock(&m_CriticalSection, TRUE);

    // do work here.

    // The critical section will be unlocked when myLock goes out of scope
}
```

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a `description` that helps to explain your code.  Thanks